# Why does the any() method not return what I think it should?

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up a bot that deletes messages if they include a specific string from a list anywhere in their body.

This code works exactly how I think it should: (returns True)

```
s = 'test upvote test'
upvote_strings = ['upvote', 'up vote', 'doot']
print(any(x in s for x in upvote_strings))
```

But this does not: (returns False)

```
s = 'your upvotе bot thing works fine lmao'
upvote_strings = ['upvote', 'up vote', 'doot']
print(any(x in s for x in upvote_strings))
```

Comment: I think there's a "weird" character in 's'.  Copy&Paste *s* into the console and you will see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of those e is not ASCII:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(s[10])
'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE'
>>> unicodedata.name(upvote_strings[0][-1])
'LATIN SMALL LETTER E'
```

[`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) can help:

```
>>> e1 = s[10] 
>>> e2 = upvote_strings[0][-1] 
>>> e1 == e2 
False
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(e1) == "e" == unidecode(e2)
True
```

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: I can't get unidecode to import with `from unidecode import unidecode`, am I missing anything?

Comment: You gotta install that. It's not stdlib.

Comment: Figured it out with `pip3 install unidecode`, for anyone else trying to figure this out in the future. Thanks!